# Java replaceAll cannot replace a character in a string

Tags: java, regex, unicode, text-processing

I want to replace the Arabic Letter Heh (U+0647) to the Arabic Letter Ae (U+06D5) in a given string using Java `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method. I have this code:

```
String arabicHeh = "\u0647‌"; // Arabic Letter Heh
String arabicAe  = "\u06D5"; // Arabic Letter Ae            

String text    = txtPane.getText();
String newText = text.replaceAll(arabicHeh, arabicAe);
```

When I print `newText` variable nothing is changed, the letter `arabicHeh` is still exist in the string.

Note: The code works when I write it in this way:

```
String newText = text.replaceAll("ه", arabicAe);
```

In other words, the code works when I make the Arabic Letter Heh itself as a parameter to `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`, but I don't want to write the character `"ه"` itself inside my code because not all IDEs can read/show this character.

I think `arabibHeh` has problem, because also `text.contains(arabicHeh)` evaluates to `false` while it definitely contains `arabicHeh`, I thought may be the problem is in getting text from the `JTextPane` (`String text = txtPane.getText();`)  but when I print `text` to console I get the same text as typed in the `JTextPane`, including the `arabicHeh`.

Anyone kindly can explain why `text.contains(arabicHeh)` evaluates to `false` or why the code is not working in `text.replaceAll(arabicHeh, arabicAe)`?

Comment: you should try to print `arabicHeh`or `arabicAe` to see is it correct

Comment: You should include original `text` value

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not clear. @CSK

Comment: i am trying to teaching how to fish. not giving fish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copypasted your snippet I've got space after \u0647‌

```
String arabicHeh = "\u0647‌ "; // Arabic Letter Heh
```

It is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner

just remove it from your code snippet and all will work :)

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you right there is a hidden character (ZWNJ), which cannot be seen with the naked eyes.  I am working on non-English (Kurdish Sorani) text, perhaps during switching the keyboard I typed this hidden character mistakenly

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex. Don't use `String`. Just use plain char replace:

```
char arabicHeh = 0x0647;
char arabicAe  = 0x06D5;

String newText = text.replace(arabicHeh, arabicAe);
```

`replace()` still replaces all occurrences, but it doesn't use regex *and* it has an overloaded version that accepts `char` parameters.

This code worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, your code works very well, but sorry I cannot flag it as the right answer since @Denis Kurochkin found the error on my code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with fonts (in your console or application) because both

```
"\u0647".replaceAll(arabicHeh, arabicAe).equals("\u06D5")
"\u06D5".replaceAll(arabicAe, arabicHeh).equals("\u0647")
```

evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Than you for your comment, when I run your code I get false for both lines. I tried different IDEs:  NetBeans IDE 8.1 and  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)). In both IDEs I get false.

Comment: I think the problem is `arabicHeh`, because when I try other characters I get true, for example : `String arabicKaf            = "\u0643"; // Arabic Letter Kaf 
         String arabicKeheh          = "\u06A9"; // Arabic Letter Keheh
         
   System.out.println("\u0643".replaceAll(arabicKaf, arabicKeheh).equals("\u06A9"));
      System.out.println("\u06A9".replaceAll(arabicKeheh, arabicKaf).equals("\u0643"));`

Comment: @DelmanAbdullah It might be a jdk bug also. what java version do you use?

Comment: I am using this JDK:
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)